# как передать ajax POST на локальный сервер

Tags: javascript, php, django, post

Есть проект django, сервер apache2, система Ubuntu18.04, в проекте js скрипт, из которого нужно отправить POST-запрос в php скрипт на локальном сервере. Присвоил айпишнику 127.0.0.1 домен myserver.com в /etc/hosts, настроил в апаче корневую папку /web. Но попытка отправить запрос на сервер приводит к ошибке

```
POST http://myserver.com/script/ net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

Если вместо домена поставить адрес локалхоста, то данная ошибка не возникает, но возникает ошибка CORS:

```
POST http://localhost/script/ 404 (Not Found)
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/script/' from origin 'http://site.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Но на моем компе на винде при таких же настройках все прекрасно работает.

script.js:

```
sendMail: function (formid) {
        var formId = "#" + formid;
        var fd = new FormData(document.querySelector(formId));
        var url = 'http://myserver.com/script/';
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            data: fd,
            cache: true,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            beforeSend: function () {
...
```

index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>myserver</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>myserver</h2>
  <?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
    require_once 'script.php';
  ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А все до безобразия банально. Клиентский js естественно стучится на локальный хост клиента, а не сайта, и естественно ничего там не видит. Отсюда и все ошибки. Надо сначала передать запрос на сайт, а уже из сайта - на локальный сервер. Либо вешать серверу белый айпишник.

Answer (score 3):

```
var url = '/script/index.php';
```

Лучше всего url - делать "Относительные ссылки к файлам", и тогда при переносе сайта с одного сервера к другому, ничего меняться не будет.

Comment: я не набрал ещё 50 репутации по этому не могу оставлять коментарии к вашему посту...

Comment: Лучше напишите в ответе подробнее что вы имели ввиду. Подробные комментарии вполне могут стать ответами :)

Comment: Скрипт находится за пределами папки проекта, поэтому относительный путь не пройдет. Если запихать скрипт в папку проекта, то php сервер не будет его обрабатывать, а питон не работает с php.

Comment: Хорошо, но в любом случае пропишите в URL - и имя файла... проверьте если работает...

Comment: при добавлении имени файла в конце урла ничего не поменялось

Comment: https://appuals.com/how-to-fix-error-err_name_not_resolved-on-google-chrome/